# VB.net access data from 2 select statement in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to access the result from 2 select statement in vb.net, but I can only access the data from the 1st select statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_testproc] 
AS    
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   

    SELECT 
        comp_name, p_center, branch_id
    FROM 
        tbl_company B 
    INNER JOIN
        tbl_b_office X ON X.batch_id = B.tran_id
    WHERE
        X.office_stat = 1
    ORDER BY 
        comp_name ASC;

    SELECT 
        xcomp_name, xp_center, xbranch_id
    FROM
        tbl_company B 
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_b_office X ON X.batch_id = B.tran_id
    WHERE
        X.office_stat = 0
        AND MONTH(X.post_dt) = MONTH(GETDATE())
        AND YEAR(X.post_dt) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    ORDER BY
        comp_name ASC;   
END
```

Example if I try to get the result for data in 2nd table

```
getData(intRow).xcomp_name
```

This gets the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But this would get the data

```
getData(intRow).comp_name
```

will get the value of the field.

Answer (score 2):

Collect the output data to a `Dataset` so that, you can take the result of first `select query` from the `DataTable` in the 0th index of the dataset.

this May help you:

```
Dim myDataSet=GetDataSetFromSP("yourSPName")
Dim FirstResult As DataTable=myDataSet.Tables(0) 
Dim SecontResult As DataTable=myDataSet.Tables(1)
```

Here you have to write the function that will execute the SP and return `DataSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also combine the 2 queries into one.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_testproc] 
AS    
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   

    SELECT 
        comp_name, p_center, branch_id, xcomp_name, xp_center, xbranch_id
    FROM 
        tbl_company B 
    INNER JOIN
        tbl_b_office X ON X.batch_id = B.tran_id
    WHERE
        X.office_stat = 1 
        OR
        (
         X.office_stat = 0
         AND MONTH(X.post_dt) = MONTH(GETDATE())
         AND YEAR(X.post_dt) = YEAR(GETDATE())
        )
    ORDER BY 
        comp_name ASC;
END
```

Then in the code, check the value of office_stat and continue accordingly.